Recurring rpm database corruption
I manage multiple Almalinux 8 VPS and dedicated servers, and recently I have been experiencing a lot of RPM Database corruption specifically this one:
error: rpmdb: BDB0113 Thread/process 401048/139672503925632 failed: BDB1507 Thread died in Berkeley DB library
error: db5 error(-30973) from dbenv->failchk: BDB0087 DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
error: cannot open Packages index using db5 -  (-30973)
error: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm
Error: Error: rpmdb open failed

And yes, I have run this MANY times:
mkdir -p /tmp/rpm-backup
cp -vf /var/lib/rpm/__db.* /tmp/rpm-backup
rm -vf /var/lib/rpm/__db.*

rpm --quiet -qa
rpm --rebuilddb
dnf clean all

This does solve the issue, but temporarily, and I do mean temporarily. I have one specific instance, as soon as I run dnf update -y after this, it downloads packages and tries to update it fine and as it installs, it fails with rpmdb error.
This issue is also concerning why I experienced issues like this: https://forums.almalinux.org/t/unable-to-detect-release-version/4070
I do not know what to do, there’s an underlying issue. Servers were rebooted multiple times and I do not have the experience or expertise to find out why this keeps happening and the main issue, it seems to happen with many instances I have, and not just one.
And yes, I tried following this: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3330211 it's so bad that as I try to install these packages, the database goes corrupt. I can't install these packages without running into the issue constantly.
I would appreciate any assistance in specifically how to debug this exactly and provide you guys more details for any sort of assistance.

https://rpm.org/user_doc/db_recovery.html#bdb-backend seems to offer a more robust mechanism (a dump and reload of the database data).

Thanks @MatthewIfe I will explore this and provide feedback.

In the meantime, as another temporary solution, I have implemented dcrpm to run at 23:00 every day via cron, as recommended here: https://serverfault.com/a/1046396/980228 at least for the servers that don't have severe db corruptions.

Unfortunately, this did not work @MatthewIfe, it went corrupted again. Based on that article I need to log a bug it seems. But I would prefer to first understand why this happens and see if that can be remedied before logging a bug. Any other ideas maybe?
